# Invalid URI Error on Sinatra post request

Tags: ruby, rspec, sinatra, rack

I'm working through a Sinatra demo app as part of an [RSpec tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/courses/testing-ruby-with-rspec) ([official repo](https://github.com/tutsplus/testing-ruby-with-rspec3)). The app uses an *a la carte* installation of ActiveRecord—no Rails. When I try to post a Book object to the server when running the spec, I get an *InvalidURIError*.

```
Failures:

  1) App creates a book
     Failure/Error: post :books, book: { name: "My first book" }
     URI::InvalidURIError:
       bad URI(is not URI?): books
     # /Users/andrekibbe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rack-test-0.6.3/lib/rack/test.rb:193:in `env_for'
     # /Users/andrekibbe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rack-test-0.6.3/lib/rack/test.rb:66:in `post'
     # ./spec/rack_spec.rb:10:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

**rack_spec.rb**:

```
require "environment"
require "rack_app"

fdescribe App do
  include Rack::Test::Methods

  let(:app) { App }

  it "creates a book" do
    post :books, book: { name: "My first book" }

    expect(last_response.status).to eq 201
  end
end
```

**rack_app.rb**:

```
class App < Sinatra::Base
  post '/books' do
    book = Book.new params[:book]
    if book.save
      status 201
    else
      status 502
    end
  end
end
```

**spec_helper.rb**:

```
require "environment"
require "factory_girl"
require "database_cleaner"
require "rack/test"
require_relative "./factories.rb"

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
  config.include Rack::Test::Methods

  config.before(:suite) do
    begin
      DatabaseCleaner.start
    ensure
      DatabaseCleaner.clean
    end
  end
end
```

**book.rb**:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :name
end
```

**environment.rb**:

```
require "sinatra"
require "active_record"

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  adapter: :sqlite3,
  database: File.expand_path("../../db/test.sqlite3", __FILE__)
)
```

What is it about `post :books, book: { name: "My first book" }` that make Rack see the request as a bad URI?

Comment: What happens if you try:  `post '/books', book: {....}`?

Comment: Or even: `post :'/books', ....`

Comment: @7stud `post '/books', book: {....}` yields a syntax error: `(SyntaxError)
    post :books, book: {....}
                           ^`. Same with `post :'/books', ....`: `(SyntaxError)
    post :books, ....
                    ^`

Comment: Edit your question, and at the bottom repost the exact code that produced the error, i.e. rack_spec.rb, and post the full error message underneath.

Comment: Not sure how I'd reorganize the code I posted to make it any clearer. The *rack_spec.rb* code that executed when I ran `rspec --tag focus` yielded the error message directly above the code listing—so the error message at the beginning of the post is followed directly by the code that produced it. Maybe I'll can move the *rack_app.rb* application code so that it appear right after the spec. s

Comment: I moved *rack_app.rb* so that it appears right after *rack_spec.rb*, but I still think that the error lies in the spec's post request, not in the AR model.

Comment: Okay, let's slow down a bit. 1) I asked you to make some code changes.  Did you make them?  If you did, I want you to post that exact code, i.e. the whole file that contains the code changes.  2) The code changes I suggested purportedly produced a new error message.  I want you to post the full text of that error message.  3)  I want you to post #1 and # 2 at the end of your question, so draw a line across the bottom of your question, and below that line, post what I asked for in #1 and #2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works for me if you make the changes I recommended in the comment, however, if you literally used the following in your code:

```
post '/books', book: {...}
```

or:

```
post :'/books', ...
```

...then of course those lines won't work.  The `...` means "the same as your original code because it is a waste of my time to type that".  Here is what the recommended change should look like:

**rack_app.rb**:

```
require "environment"
require "rack_app"

fdescribe App do
  let(:app) { App }

  it "creates a book" do
    post '/books', book: { name: "My brand new book" }
    expect(last_response.status).to eq 201
  end
end
```

The only route your App defined is here:

```
class App < Sinatra::Base
  #       +--------This is the only url your App responds to  
  #       |        and ONLY if it is contained in a post request
  #       V
  post '/books' do

    book = Book.new params[:book]

    if book.save
      status 201
    else
      status 502
    end

  end

end
```

Even using a Symbol as the url doesn't work:

```
  it "creates a book" do
    post :'/books', book: { name: "My brand new book" }
```

And, because a Symbol won't work for the url in your rspec test, that means that Sinatra takes the first argument given to post(), e.g. `:'/books'`, and compares it to the route(s) you defined in your App class:

```
defined_route = '/books'
requested_route = :'/books'

if requested_route != defined_route
  puts "URI ERROR"
end

--output:--
URI ERROR
```

Comment: Ah, that did it.. Once you pointed about that I was posting to a symbol, and not a path, it was obvious in hindsight. That's what I get for blindly typing in the tutorial code without actually thinking about it. Thanks!

Comment: @Gameboy70, That is why in the second go round I asked you to post the exact code containing the changes that you ran, and the full text of the new error message.  If you had posted the altered code, I could have quickly spotted what was wrong...but for some reason you refused.  Just so you know, it is required that you post the exact code and the full error message for any code you run. You can't just say, "Hey, I made the changes, and now I get this error."